Timeline frame advance in Action Recorder
I am using the Action recorder add-on. I am copying and pasting a pose. In between copy and paste I want to advance the timeline by just one frame, usually achieved by using the right arrow key. Action recorder doesn't pick see this keyboard action.
Anyone have any ideas how else I can get action recorder to recognise how to move the time line marker by one frame in the middle of a macro
Many thanks
RiChap

That appears to be a third-party addon which is not supplied with Blender so you should ask the addon author.
